# Adding active class doesn't affect toggle button in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with multi checkbox which is required field that I turned into twitter bootstrap toggle buttons.

I am trying to activate a selection button with js, by adding 'active' class to it.
I am able to add the class but when saving the form I am getting an error that the field is required.

What am I missing?

Here is the form.

```
<div id="reminder">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" name="reminder" id="id_reminder_1" value="1" title="Choose at least one reminder option">Now</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" name="reminder" id="id_reminder_2" value="30" title="Choose at least one reminder option">30m</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" name="reminder" id="id_reminder_3" value="60" title="Choose at least one reminder option">1h</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" name="reminder" id="id_reminder_4" value="120"
            title="Choose at least one reminder option">2h</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" name="reminder" id="id_reminder_5" value="1440"
            title="Choose at least one reminder option">1d</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how I am adding the class:

```
    $('#reminder label:eq(3)').addClass('active')
```

Comment: There is no element with id of `div_id_reminder` in your markup. It should be `$('#reminder label:eq(3)')` ?

Comment: Just a typing mistake.
But this is not the issue.

Comment: why don't you make a fiddle?

Comment: i know this is quite late, but you may still want to have a look through the answers and select a correct one...?

Answer (score 1):

You're only adding the class, but you don't actually select it. Add the `selected` attribute and it will work:

```
$('#reminder label:eq(3)').addClass('active').attr('selected',true);
```

**[Here is a demo](http://www.bootply.com/P9fxBJ0pho)**

Answer (score 0):

Add class `open` not `active` to open the dropdown (if thats what you are trying to do). You have to add the class to `<li class='dropdown open'>` which hosts the `<ul class='dropdown-menu'>`

Comment: I am not using a dropdown menu, I am using bootstrap buttons.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Comment: have u tried adding `open` instead of `active` class? make sure you add it at the right place.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but you are replying to something not relevant to me.

I dont have any issue with dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

btn-primary is the css that will make your buttons blue. It looks like this is what you are using for inactive buttons because the way you have your code, all the buttons should be blue. If you are trying to make the button grey because grey will be your active button, then you can use removeClass('btn-primary'). This will turn it grey. Hope this helps.